# a UDP socket based rateless file transmission

Tags: multithreading, sockets, process, udp

I'm new to socket programming and I need to implement a UDP based rateless file transmission system to verify a scheme in my research. Here is what I need to do:

I want a server S to send a file to a group of peers A, B, C.., etc. The file is divided into a number of packets. At the beginning, peers will send a Request message to the server to initialize transmission. Whenever S receives a request from a client, it ratelessly transmit encoded packets(how to encode is done by my design, the encoding itself has the erasure-correction capability, that's why I can transmit ratelessly via UDP) to that client. The client keeps collecting packets and try to decode them. When it finally decodes all packets and re-construct the file successfully, it sends back a Stop message to the server and S will stop transmitting to this client.

Peers request the file asynchronously (they may request the file at different time). And the server will have to be able to concurrently serve multiple peers. The encoded packets for different clients are different (they are all encoded from the same set source packets, though).

Here is what I'm thinking about the implementation. I have not much experience with unix network programming though, so I'm wondering if you can help me assess it, and see if it is possible or efficient.

1. I'm gonna implement the server as a concurrent UDP server with two socket ports(similar to TFTP according to the UNP book). One is to receive controlling messages, as in my context it is for the Request and Stop messages. The server will maintain a flag (=1 initially) for each request. When it receives a Stop message from the client, the flag will be set to 0.
2. When the serve receives a request, it will fork() a new process that use the second socket and port to send encoded packets to the client. The server keeps sending packets to the client as long as the flag is 1. When it turns to 0, the sending ends.
3. The client program is easy to do. Just send a Request, recvfrom() the server, progressively decode the file and send a Stop message in the end.

Is this design workable? The main concerns I have are: (1), is that efficient by forking multiple processes? Or should I use threads? (2), If I have to use multiple processes, how can the flag bit be known by the child process? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: what programming language do you use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Using UDB for file transfer is not best idea. There is no way for server or client to know if any packet has been lost so you would only know that during reconstruction assuming you have some mechanism (like counter) to detect lost packes. It would then be hard to request just one of those packets that got lost. And in the end you would have a code that would do what TCP sockets do. So I suggest to start with TCP.

Typical design of a server involves a listener thread that spawns a worker thread whenever there is a new client request. That new thread would handle communication with that particular client and then end. You should keep a limit of clients (threads) that are served simultaneously. Do not spawn a new process for each client - that is inefficient and not needed as this will get you nothing that you can't achieve with threads.

Thread programming requires carefulness so do not cut corners. Otherwise you will have hard time finding and diagnosing problems.

Comment: My encoding scheme has a kind of erasure-correcting capability, so no re-transmission is needed. The principle is, for n source packets, any n or a slightly more than n encoded packets received are able to recover the n source packets successfully. One excellent code represents this idea is called LT(Luby-Transform) codes. With this feature, using UDP may save protocol overhead and handshaking time. However, the decoding would be time consuming, that is why I want to examine the implementation to see whether this trade-off between protocol overhead and decoding time is worthy or not.

Comment: BTW, when spawn a new thread to communicate with the client, I _have_ to generate another socket in that thread and use a new port for that client, right?

Comment: Yes, you need new socket to communicate back to each client. With UDP you could use the same socket but since there would be new thread for each client you should create new socket for each thread.

Comment: Just a tiny question, is that okay to use the sockaddr_in structure of the client when it requests the transmission (returned by the kernel when the server doing recvfrom() in the listener thread) with the new socket in the worker thread? I'm sorry if this question is stupid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another thought, maybe I can just maintain two sockets one different ports. One for the listener, the other for the worker. The listener socket is just for receiving(control messages, basically Request and Stop). The server will maintain a list of requested clients' address. The worker socket is for sending only. So there are only 2 sockets and 2 threads needed, right? Whenever a controlling message is received, a mutex is used to modify clients information such that the worker thread can be informed (add a new client or remove it). Is this design reasonable? Thanks sincerely.

Comment: It's much better that each thread had its own socket to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

File transfer with UDP wil be fun :(

Your struct/class for each message should contain a sequence number and a checksum.  This should enable each client to detect, and ask for the retransmission of, any missing blocks at the end of the transfer.

Where UDP might be a huge winner is on a local LAN.  You could UDP-broadcast the entire file to all clients at once and then, at the end, ask each client in turn which blocks it has missing and send just those.  I wish Kaspersky etc. would use such a scheme for updating all my local boxes.

I have used such a broadcast scheme on a CANBUS network where there are dozens of microControllers that need new images downloaded.  Software upgrades take minutes instead of hours.